# Sequential file IO from different threads fail with FileSystemException

Tags: java, multithreading, windows-7, io

I am trying to see how fast i can do something like:

1. write a small file
2. rename it
3. delete it

This basically looks like:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;


public class QuickIO {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path fileToWriteTo = Paths.get("C:\\Temp\\somefile.txt");
    Path fileToMoveTo = Paths.get("C:\\Temp\\someotherfile.txt");
    Files.write(fileToWriteTo, "sometext".getBytes());
    Files.move(fileToWriteTo, fileToMoveTo);
    Files.delete(fileToMoveTo);
  }

}
```

The above works absolutely fine. 
I'd want to do the same with a large number of files to get relevant figures; each operation should be done by a different thread (which resembles my end architecture). They would communicate via blocking queues (hence each operation on a file would be done when no other thread is working on it). I'm running this on windows 7 and it fails with the following:

```
10:21:39.756 [Thread-1] WARN  FileMover - IOException
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Temp\file_0.in -> C:\Temp\file_0.in\file_0.out: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:86) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(WindowsFileCopy.java:387) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:287) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1347) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at FileMover.run(FileMover.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_67]
```

So basically the write operation works fine, hands over a Path object to the FileMover which tries to move the file, but this fails as the file is "used" by another process. Nothing else is using that file as it was just created and the process that created it closed the file as ensured by Files.write().

**Any idea why does the file system sees the file still in use when it shouldn't? And how to solve it? :)**

Here is the whole code for that (call with "java App C:\Temp 1" for just one file and this fails)

App.java

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class App {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(args.length != 2 ) {
      System.exit(1);
    }
    Path workDir = Paths.get(args[0]);
    int numFilesToWrite = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

    if(!Files.isDirectory(workDir)) {
      System.exit(1);
    }

    if(numFilesToWrite < 1) {
      System.exit(1);
    }

    BlockingQueue<Path> fromFileWriterToFileMover = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Path>();
    BlockingQueue<Path> fromFileMoverToFileRemover = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Path>();

    Thread writer = new Thread(new FileWriter(workDir, fromFileWriterToFileMover, numFilesToWrite));
    Thread mover = new Thread(new FileMover(fromFileWriterToFileMover, fromFileMoverToFileRemover));
    Thread remover = new Thread(new FileRemover(fromFileMoverToFileRemover));

    remover.start();
    mover.start();
    writer.start();

  }

}
```

FileWrite.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class FileWriter implements Runnable {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileWriter.class);

  Path workDirectory;
  BlockingQueue<Path> toFileMover;
  int numFiles;

  public FileWriter(
      Path workDirectory,
      BlockingQueue<Path> toFileMover,
      int numFiles) {
    this.workDirectory = workDirectory;
    this.toFileMover = toFileMover;
    this.numFiles = numFiles;
  }

  public void run() {
    RandomString rs = new RandomString(2345);
    long msSpentWritingFiles = 0L;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < numFiles ; i++) {
      try {
        Path file = workDirectory.resolve(Paths.get("file_" + i + ".in"));

        byte [] bytes = rs.nextString().getBytes();
        long beforeWrite = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Files.write(file, bytes);
        long afterWrite = System.currentTimeMillis();
        msSpentWritingFiles = msSpentWritingFiles + (afterWrite - beforeWrite);

        toFileMover.put(file);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        log.warn("IO Exception", e);
      }
      catch (InterruptedException e) {
        log.warn("InterruptedException", e);
      }
    }

    Path endPath = Paths.get("/THEEND");
    try {
      toFileMover.put(endPath);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      log.warn("InterruptedException", e);
    }

    log.info("Time spent writing files: " + msSpentWritingFiles + "ms");
  }

}
```

FileMover.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class FileMover implements Runnable {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileMover.class);

  BlockingQueue<Path> fromFileWriter;
  BlockingQueue<Path> toFileRemover;

  public FileMover(
      BlockingQueue<Path> fromFileWriter,
      BlockingQueue<Path> toFileRemover) {
    this.fromFileWriter = fromFileWriter;
    this.toFileRemover = toFileRemover;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    boolean carryOn = true;
    long msSpentMovingFiles = 0L;

    while(carryOn) {
      try {
        Path origin = fromFileWriter.take();

        if("THEEND".equals(origin.getFileName().toString())){
          carryOn = false;
          toFileRemover.put(origin);
        } else {

          Path destination = origin.resolve(origin.getFileName().toString().replace(".in", ".out"));
          long beforeMove = System.currentTimeMillis();
          Files.move(origin, destination);
          long afterMove = System.currentTimeMillis();

          msSpentMovingFiles = msSpentMovingFiles + (afterMove - beforeMove);

          toFileRemover.put(destination);
        }

      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        log.warn("InterruptedException", e);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        log.warn("IOException", e);
      }

    }
    log.info("Time spent moving files: " + msSpentMovingFiles + "ms");
  }
}
```

FileRemover.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class FileRemover implements Runnable {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileRemover.class);

  BlockingQueue<Path> fromFileMover;

  public FileRemover(BlockingQueue<Path> fromFileMover) {
    this.fromFileMover = fromFileMover;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    boolean carryOn = true;
    long msSpentDeletingFiles = 0L;

    while(carryOn) {
      try {
        Path fileToDelete = fromFileMover.take();

        if("THEEND".equals(fileToDelete.getFileName().toString())){
          carryOn = false;
        } else {


          long beforeDelete = System.currentTimeMillis();
          Files.delete(fileToDelete);
          long afterDelete = System.currentTimeMillis();

          msSpentDeletingFiles = msSpentDeletingFiles + (afterDelete - beforeDelete);

        }
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        log.warn("InterruptedException", e);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        log.warn("IOException", e);
      }

    }
    log.info("Time spent deleting files: " + msSpentDeletingFiles + "ms");
  }

}
```

RandomString.java

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomString {

  private static final char[] symbols;

  static {
    StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder();
    for (char ch = '0'; ch <= '9'; ++ch)
      tmp.append(ch);
    for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ++ch)
      tmp.append(ch);
    symbols = tmp.toString().toCharArray();
  }   

  private final Random random = new Random();

  private final char[] buf;

  public RandomString(int length) {
    if (length < 1)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("length < 1: " + length);
    buf = new char[length];
  }

  public String nextString() {
    for (int idx = 0; idx < buf.length; ++idx) 
      buf[idx] = symbols[random.nextInt(symbols.length)];
    return new String(buf);
  }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>small-file-writer</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <logback.version>1.1.2</logback.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.10</slf4j.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>${java.version}</source>
          <target>${java.version}</target>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: In your BlockingQueue you put path objects and not file objects. A path is not a file! Think of a path like a pointer to a file, so while the path is added to the queue, the file in background may not be ready at all. Try to do it with a BlockingQueue with File. Before you add, secure that the file is fully written or moved. This could be a workaround for the Path also.

Comment: A File is not a file either! :) A File is "An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames". Path is simply a newer, better version of File. Each of the file operations ensures that the underlying file is closed before returning. Only after the operation completes is the Path handed to the next thread via queue, hence the operations on a single file are sequential.

Comment: You're right, but the path object will not be noticed **when** the close / finish will happen. The same on a file object. You and the GC are responsible for doing this. Maybe a more thing with Threading like calling join to wait for thread finishes?

Comment: You cannot close a File object. Only an OutputStream, which is done by the Files.write(Path path, byte[] bytes, OpenOption... options) method, which explicitly says in its JavaDoc "The method ensures that the file is closed when all bytes have been written". If there was a problem with that, my first example using QuickIO should fail.

Comment: Now we got it :-) BTW: Files.write() calls a synchronized outputstream methods, so this should block for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply had some typo in your **FileMover** run method:

```
Path destination = origin.resolve(origin.getFileName().toString().replace(".in", ".out"));
```

The destination will be like *C:\temp\file_0.in\file_0.out* this won't work, because it is a file and not a directory :-)

Replace it something like that:

```
String now = origin.toString().replace(".in", ".out");
Path destination = Paths.get(now);
```

Comment: You're welcome! My persistence maybe comes from drinking a good Islay from time to time :-)